# Using Google Pay api on Chrome Web Store Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-pay

I know Chrome Web Store has a own built-in payment system, and all the guide about the use of that payment system.

But the Google Pay API are also support for web "[The Google Pay API enables fast, simple checkout on your website.](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/overview)". And Extension is actually a JavaScript web. So can I just use the Google Pay API on the Extension? Does it would violate the Web Store policy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of this being done.

In order to integrate with Google Pay directly, you will need to [sign up for a Merchant account with Google](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/test-and-deploy/request-prod-access) and one of the requirements for that is for Google to be able to review your site/app. Assuming you go through this process, there technically isn't any reason why it *shouldn't* work (I think).

I think the devil will be in the detail like the actual use case, how the extension is implemented and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work currently. The Google Pay's `pay.js` displays these errors in the console:

```
Only localhost, file://, and cryptographic scheme origins allowed.
No UI will be shown. CanMakePayment and hasEnrolledInstrument will always return false. Show will be rejected with NotSupportedError.
```

Looks like the issue is, that the extensions protocol is `chrome-extension://` and only `https://` is allowed by Google Pay.